# Retrieve list or set element in cassandra by index

Tags: list, select, cassandra, set, cql

i'm importing json data to cassandra. Here is one of my table :

```
CREATE TABLE Geometry (
id TEXT, type TEXT, coordinates LIST<FLOAT>,
primary key (id)
);
```

As you can see I have `coordinates` which is a list of 3 elements like: [-12, 123, 4].
I would like to know if it's possible in Cassandra to retrieve only the last element of `coordinates` to do a query like :

```
select coordinates[2] from geometry where id='nc72001620';
```

Which would retrieve me 4 in my example.
Note that I could change coordinates to a set if it's necessary.
Thank you !